# Celery + django - pdf generator

Tags: python, django, pdf, celery

I have some question: how to catch a pdf file which I generated in tasks.py and start downloading it automatically after redirect to home page and put the download link into this page? My task.py works because I see the result in terminal.

My tasks.py:

```
@shared_task
def html_to_pdf(ctx):
    html_string = render_to_string('pdf_template.html', ctx)
    html = HTML(string=html_string)
    html.write_pdf('/tmp/report.pdf')

    fs = FileSystemStorage('/tmp')
    with fs.open('report.pdf') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] \
            = 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"'
        return response
```

My views.py:

```
class PdfCreatorView(View):

def get(self, request):
    form = PdfForm
    return render(request, 'home_page.html', {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = PdfForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        date_of_generation = form.cleaned_data['date_of_generation']
        pdf_text_content = form.cleaned_data['pdf_text_content']
        pdf_numbers_content = form.cleaned_data['pdf_numbers_content']
        ctx = {'name': name,
               'date_of_generation': date_of_generation,
               'pdf_text_content': pdf_text_content,
               'pdf_numbers_content': pdf_numbers_content}

        html_to_pdf.delay(ctx)

        url = reverse('home_page')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your celery task is executed out-of-time with the response (hence task.delay()). By the time they reach that page the task is more than likely still working on generating the PDF. If you want to run this task and then wait, you can do

```
    ctx = {'name': name,
           'date_of_generation': date_of_generation,
           'pdf_text_content': pdf_text_content,
           'pdf_numbers_content': pdf_numbers_content}

    tsk = html_to_pdf.apply_async(ctx)
    ret = tsk.get()

    url = reverse('home_page')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Then what I would do is figure out a way to make another endpoint that supplies the file instead of offering it as a Response object.

Comment: Your code gave my **EncodeErroe: <HttpResponse status_code=200, "application/pdf"> is not JSON serializable** any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Found the problem, is a **CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND** how to configure this to working with PDF-s?

Comment: If you want to get the return of that celery task it can't be an HttpResponse, it will need to be a serializable type such as a string, int, dict, list